# Why the unexpected results in my insertion sort?

Tags: javascript, sorting, swap

I made this insertion sort:

```js
function selection(arr) {
     arr.forEach((cur, index) => {
       var min = index;
       for(var j = index + 1, max = arr.length; j < max; j++) {
           var cur = arr[j];
           if(cur < arr[min]) min = j;
       }
       /* Permutations without temporary var */
       arr[index] = arr[index] + arr[min];
       arr[min] = arr[index] - arr[min];
       arr[index] = arr[index] - arr[min];
     });
     return arr;
   }


   var array = [1, 9 ,2, 20, 21, 22, 19, 18, 25, 10];
   
   console.log(selection(array));
```

When I use a temporary variable, to make the permutation the result is the expected one. The problem comes when I do NOT use a temporary variable for the permutation, and instead of that, I use the method to do it without a temporary variable using addition and subtraction. And this is when I get unexpected and unsuccessful results, what am I wrong in doing the insertion sort WITHOUT a temporary variable? ,

Comment: @LukStorms Yes that is intended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add condition before swapping the elements (When needed).

```
...code
if(index != min){
    arr[index] = arr[index] + arr[min];
    arr[min] = arr[index] - arr[min];
    arr[index] = arr[index] - arr[min];
}
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of the [XOR swap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor_swap). Which doesn't work at all when it's swapping a memory location with itself, canceling the value out (producing `0`). It's happening in your case when `min == index` - when the smallest value is already at the lowest position.